# Asterisk/TrixBox and Predictive Dialing/Outbound Call Center

Tags: asterisk, trixbox

Is anyone out there running predictive dialers or Call Center type products on Asterisk/Trixbox.  I'm looking for [vicidial](http://www.vicidial.org/vicidial.php) type functionality.  The best way to characterize it would be political campaigning or marketing surveys.

Also, I really am just trolling for good or bad news either way on the product.

As I don't really have a problem per se, this might need to be marked Community Wiki.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use Vicidial for as much as 220 seats at a time with a multi-server Asterisk setup. It performs very well. We have in-house programmers that do the customization of the CRM, etc. for us so it's also very cost-effective.

You could contact a consultant from their webpage:

http://www.vicidial.com/

Comment: That's what we use.  Can't say enough good things about them.

Answer (score 1):

We looked into this about 18 months ago. We ended up going with a different provider (not Asterisk) but from memory the choices were mostly fairly poor, especially for highly customised environments. And their interfaces were all clearly an afterthought designed by someone with only basic HTML skills.

In the end we went with a VoIP provider called Swyx, and then wrote our own predictive dialling code using their extensive and well documented ActiveX API (integrated it into the Do Not Call register, automatic callback requests when calls failed or went to answering machine, etc).